# MissingMethodException in MainActivity Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]

---

This exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: void Xamarin.Forms.Internals.Profile.FrameBegin(string,string,int)'

How can I solve this trouble?

My Code:

```cs
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        global::Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, savedInstanceState); // инициализация плагина pop-up
        CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
        Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Color.Teal);
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Teal);
    }
}
```

Comment: upgrade nuget packages on both shared and Android projects

Comment: I'm upgradet packages, but don't result

Comment: try clearing nuget cache, project clean, rebuild, uninstall and deploy

Comment: No, I'm tried, but this is solution don't helped me

Comment: I your code in the `MainActivity`, my nuget package version like this sceenshot. https://imgur.com/a/4F8tnCd